# Convert dateTime format and Store into database

Tags: database, datetime

I am currently using AJAX tools for calendar. For example, when I select 25/12/2013 (dd/M/yyyy) from calendar, the text box itself displays in another ways around which is 12/25/2013 (M/dd/yyyy). Here is the codes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDate" runat="server" Style="height: 34px; width: 150px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:CalendarExtender
                                    ID="CalendarExtender1"
                                    TargetControlID="tbStartDate"
                                    runat="server" />
```

And before I try to pass it into the data access layer, I converted it:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(tbStartDate.Text, "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, it gives me an error message which is The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar. I know the Gregorian Calendar was in M/dd/yyyy format. However, for the Sql, which is this format: dd/M/yyyy. I wonder how can I convert from user input and store it into database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in CalendarExtender

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" 
                      TargetControlID="tbStartDate" 
                      runat="server" 
                      Format="dd/M/yyyy" />
```

Comment: It works perfectly. And my DateTime.ParseExact() works well with that! Thanks a lot!!